# concatenating a jquery variable to a string in order to add id's to dynamically generated input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically add input fields according to an amount specified in a separate input field. I have managed to get this mostly working by using jquery code from a similar question that was asked on SO. What I have been unable to do is concatenate an 'id' var to the id of the input field.

Sorry of I am being vague, I will include all code below so you can see what I am trying to do. Also, some of the html form code is not standard as I am using the Laravel Framework.

**HTML**

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'add_columns/' . $page, 'class' => 'pure-form pure-form-stacked']) }}
                    <div class="pure-g">
                        <div class="pure-u-1-2">
                            <p><b>Amount of columns to add: </b></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="pure-u-1-2">
                            {{ Form::text('qty', null, ['style' => 'width: 3em;', 'id' => 'qty']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="newFields"></div>

                    {{ Form::submit('add', ['class' => 'pure-button pure-button-primary']) }}

                {{ Form::close() }}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {

//var input = $('{{ Form::text("awe", null, ["placeholder" => "column"]) }}');
var newFields = $('');
var id = $(1);

$('#qty').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
    var n = this.value || 0;
    if (n+1) {
        if (n > newFields.length) {
            addFields(n);
        } else {
            removeFields(n);
        }
    }
});

function addFields(n) {
    for (i = newFields.length; i < n; i++) {
        var newInput = $('{{ Form::text("' + id + '", null, ["placeholder" => "column"]) }}');
        newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
        newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
        id++;
    }
}

function removeFields(n) {
    var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
    newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
}
```

});

This results in  when what I need is

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: {{ Form: }} is something that the server generates not the client. If you look at the markup after you page renders I am pretty sure you are going to be looking at <input> tags.

Comment: no, the inputs I am writing are not generated by the server, the server interprets them as <input> and either way, why does that matter

Comment: it matters in that you are asking jquery to create an input field and add it to your page and there is no input (as in <input> tag) created. I will bet if you change it to var newInput = $('<input type="textbox" value="somthing" />') and add it to newInput it should get rendered. {{ Form::Submit }} is that AngularJs?

Comment: But as far as I understand jquery, im just asking it to output text in that script. In which case being in the format {{ Form:: }} or <input> shouldnt matter but I will give it a go either way

Comment: I'm thinking it matters because if you are using Angular that notation is still getting at somepoint interpreted into HTML to be rendered on a page. I doubt the browser knows that {{ Form::text }} stands for a textbox.

Comment: Ok I gave it a go and got a different result - but not what I want. i got id="[Object Object]" as a result? Any ideas? also if you try solve this could you give a go at formatting it in the {{ Form:: }} method? **edit** i made a typo. It works as you said, though would it still be posible to create the inputs in the form {{ Form }}?

Comment: I have dabbled a little with angular although not lately so not really sure if it has a built in capability to do what you are wanting from it. I know Angularjs has it's own way of manipulating the DOM without the need for writing Jquery.

Comment: Im using jquery though? not angular?

Answer (score 0):

```
function addFields(n) {
    for (i = newFields.length; i < n; i++) {
        var newInput = $('<input id="index' + i + '" type="text" placeholder="column">');
        newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
        newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works - though is it possible to output {{ Form::text() }} instead?

Comment: Sorry, this is jQuery, all `{{ Form::text }}` gives `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression`.

Answer (score 0):

In essense Julien, the {{ Form:text() }} is eventually rendered as  If you look at the HTML that is rendered on your browser you won't see any {{ Form:text() }} tags. Is there a particular reason you want it in this way or is it just to keep it uniformal? What advantage is the {{ Form:text() }} giving you?

Comment: just curious if it is possible. I will be using your solution for what I am working on, but just wondering if it was possible to stick to the {{ Form }} convention. If it will result in a lot of messy jquery fiddling then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Not unless there was a way to stick the {{Form}} convention on there and call whatever is responsible for translating that convention into the approriate HTML tag.

Comment: So in other words - a lot of unnecessary messy code. Alright well - thanks for the help!